# compose a parallepiped via sevral pairwise different cubes?

Tags: geometry

can you help me with this question :

Is it possible to compose a parallepiped via sevral (more then one) pairwise different cubes?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Certainly. If you have $abc$ cubes, you can form a parallelepiped with a rectangular base of $a \times b$ and a height of $c$, which will use up all the cubes.

The only parallelepipeds that you can get are cuboids, since all the angles of a cube are right.